# Reusing layout in extended ListActivity in Android Application

Tags: android, android-layout, listactivity

I am developing an Android application. All the screens need to have a a header with a logo and a help button and a footer with buttons to navigate between the screens. To reuse the code, I am applying the "master page" concept we have in ASP.Net as explained here:

http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2011/01/08/ldquomaster-pagesrdquo-in-android.aspx

I will have two screens with lists of objects (list of user groups and list of group members) for which I think I need to use activities that extend ListActivity.

What is the best way to do this? I've tried to create a BaseActivity that extends the Activity class and a BaseListActivity that extends ListActivity class, and then use the same XML layout file in both, but then I get a 'Source not found error' when I call the setContentView method:

```
super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
```

Comment: Do you have a file named `activity_base.xml` in `res/layout`? Also, you should be able to just call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);` with the `super` implied, though this shouldn't be an error.

Comment: Agree with @Sam. Don't call `super.setContentView` unless you are overriding `setContentView`. I don't know what you mean by "Source not found error," but if I had to guess, you are getting a runtime exception, which is causing Eclipse to open the debugger, and the location for the exception is in Android source code, which you don't have. Try checking the LogCat view to see if there is a useful exception stack trace/cause there.

Comment: I am overriding the method as shown in the link I posted, to input the layout specific to one activity in the "master" layout. I am searching in previous questions and I think the 'source not found' error is related to the fact that ActivityLists require a ListView, and I don't know how to add it in the example provided in the article. I do have a activity_base.xml file in res/layout, and it works with my BaseActivity that doesn't extend the ListActivity class.

Comment: ListActivity requires that your layout have a ListView with `android:id="@android:id/list"`... But if you can compile your code, you should post your LogCat errors so we can see what is happening.